# Parameter passing for multiple text fields that are gathered in an array?

Tags: actionscript-3

So, I have a question. I'm currently working an an education program that teaches basics on cell organelles. I have lines pointing to each organelle, in which I want to have the user be able to input what each organelle name is (like a diagram). When the user has completed the work properly, I will display the next button.

However, in order to give the user the ability to proceed, I need a way of tracking whether or not a student's answers are correct. I am using parameter passing for this.

I would like to be able to return either true/false. If all answers are returned true, the user may advance. If even one answer is wrong, a message displays.

How do I use parameter passing to determine if a users answers are right/wrong? The textfields are in an array as well...

Here is the code.

Thanks!

-Zero;

```
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var organelleInput:Array=[F18nucleolusInput_txt, F18nucleusInput_txt, F18erInput_txt, F18golgiInput_txt, F18vacuoleInput_txt, F18chloroplastInput_txt, F18lysosomeInput_txt, F18mitochondriaInput_txt]; 

F18next_btn.visible=false; 

F18next_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, F18goToFrameNineteen); 
F18back_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, F18goToFrameSix); 
checkMyWork_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkAnswers); 


function checkAnswers(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var answer:String; 
    var correctAnswers:Boolean; 
    var incorrectAnswers:Boolean; 

    answer = organelleInput[i]; 
    correctAnswers=checkCorrectAnswers(answer); 

    for(var j:int=0; j<organelleInput.length; j++)
    {
        organelleInput[j].restrict="a-z";

        if(correctAnswers==true)
        {
            F18output_txt.text="Well done!"; 
            F18next_btn.visible=true; 
            checkMyWork_btn.visible==false; 
        }

        if(correctAnswers==false)
        {
            F18output_txt.text="One of them seems to be wrong. Try again."; 
        }
    }
}



function F18goToFrameNineteen(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(19); 
}

function F18goToFrameSix(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(6); 
}

function checkCorrectAnswers(s:String):Boolean 
{
    if(F18nucleolusInput_txt.text=="nucleolus"){
        return true; 
    }
    return false; 

    if(F18nucleusInput_txt.text=="nucleus"){
        return true; 
    }
    return false; 

    if((F18erInput_txt.text=="endoplasmic reticulum")||(F18erInput_txt.text=="er")){
        return true; 
    }
    return false; 

    if((F18golgiInput_txt.text=="golgi body")||(F18golgiInput_txt.text=="golgi apparatus")){
        return true; 
    }
    return false; 

    if((F18mitochondriaInput_txt.text=="mitochondria")||(F18mitochondriaInput_txt.text=="mitochondrion")){
        return true; 
    }
    return false; 

    if((F18lysosomeInput_txt.text=="lysosome")||(F18lysosomeInput_txt.text=="lysosomes")){
        return true; 
    }
    return false; 

    if(F18vacuoleInput_txt.text=="vacuole"){
        return true; 
    }
    return false; 

    if((F18chloroplastInput_txt.text=="chloroplast")||(F18chloroplastInput_txt.text=="chloroplasts")){
        return true; 
    }
    return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check **Array** of **TextField**s vs **Array** of **Array**s:

```
var Correct:Array = [
    ["nucleolus"],
    ["nucleus"],
    ["golgi body", "golgi apparatus"],
    ["mitochondria", "mitochondrion"]
];
var Answers:Array = [T1, T2, T3, T4];

// Returns true if all answers are correct.
function allCorrect():Boolean
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < Answers.length; i++)
        if (!oneCorrect(Answers[i], Correct[i]))
            return false;

    return true;
}

// Returns true if answer is on the Array of correct answers.
function oneCorrect(source:TextField, target:Array):Boolean
{
    return target.indexOf(source.text.toLowerCase()) > -1;
}
```